# What to do when your DNS provider goes MIA?

Tags: dns, isp

I registered a couple of domain names with a VPS provider a long time ago (over 10 years).

I stopped using the VPS over two years ago, but I never discontinued the DNS name registration with them.

Flash forward: I need to reactivate e-mail to one of these domain names.  I tried re-activating the VPS.  The provider's on-line invoicing system seemed to accept the subscription ... but I never got an acknowledgement, and e-mails to support have gone unanswered.

I logged on to the DNS control panel and configured an MX record pointing my domain to a different VPS server ... but none of "ping", "dig" or "nslookup" resolve the domain name.

More support tickets to the provider ... all unanswered.  They're completely unresponsive.  And yes, I'm in the U.S.; the provider is overseas.  There's not much I can do :(

Q: What recourse do I have to somehow make use of my domain name without cooperation from my provider?

Comment: Which TLD is the domain under?

Comment: @user1686 - thank you for the help, and I'd love to give you any details you need.  Q: What do you mean by "TLD"?  It's a ".com".  Do you want the full domain name (e.g. "mycorp.com")?  Q: Wouldn't that be asking for trouble, if I broadcast the domain name here (in a very public forum)?

Comment: Yes, I was asking about just the top-level domain ('com') only. (Revealing the full domain name isn't *that* risky, but probably isn't necessary in this case.)

Comment: What status does `whois` report for your domain? As you seem to have access to the provider's management webpage, does it have a "domain transfer" section?